# django-filters and django-import-export together

Tags: django, django-import-export, django-filters

I am facing a problem:I am using django-filters to filter data from my database, and display the result through template. This works fine.
At the same time, as an option, I would like export these data to xls format, using django-import-export.
What is the best approach?
How to pass the queryset(filterset) from django-filters to django-import-export?

The FilterView is ok, the rendering to the template is ok.
I created the Resources from django-import-export, but i can't populate the queryset
Thank you for your advice